# Using $.load on Cordova HTML files not found

Tags: jquery, cordova, webview

I am using JQuery to load partial views on Cordova and everything works fine on web but when I make the build for android the html files do not exist in "android_asset".
Do I have to set any configuration to load these files? 
Can I even do this on android?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should get them as soon as you run `cordova prepare`.

Comment: Thank you, I never tried 'cordova prepare', I just used 'cordova build'. I am going to do it this way before testing everything.